# SDL_Mixer Halt halted Channels?

Tags: sdl2

It's not stated in the documentation, so I'd like to ask if anyone knows if it's ok to halt a channel (via Mix_HaltChannel()) that's been already halted?

I'm asking 'cause I'd like to halt every channel with Mix_HaltChannel(-1)(which could possibly include already halted channels) before freeing the chunks for safety reasons, because the documentation states that it's not good to free chunks of channels that are still playing.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looking quickly through the source of SDL_Mixer it does seem like doing this is safe.

The code essentially flows as the following:

- Is the channel the call wants to halt -1?

  - If yes, call `Mix_HaltChannel` on all channels.
  - If no do the following:

    - Is the wanted channel still playing?

      - If yes, stop the audio.
    - Handle fading.

So as you can see, the code actually handles the case where the channel is already halted. If you want to check it yourself, `Mix_HaltChannel` can be found in mixer.c, starting on line 1042.

Comment: Where can I actually find mixer.c?

Comment: In the source code for SDL_Mixer, downloadable from [here](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/).

Comment: @zeldahyrule Was your question answered? If it was, please accept this answer so that others can find help more easily in the future.